# Reading simple letters with Tesseract

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat lettersmat = cv::imread("letters.jpeg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::threshold(lettersmat, lettersmat, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    
    if (ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY) == 0)
        {
            ocr->SetVariable("user_defined_dpi", "96");
            ocr->SetImage(lettersmat.data, lettersmat.cols, lettersmat.rows, 1, lettersmat.step);
            std::string outText = std::string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());
    
            cout << "Text: " << endl;
            cout << outText.c_str() << endl;
    
            ocr->End();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Could not initialize Tesseract API." << endl;
        }
}
```

I can't seem to read these 4 simple letters. They're in Times New Roman. The output is nowhere near what it should be and sometimes random characters even show up.

Here's the image:
[letters.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wMs0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work a lot with Tesseract, but maybe I can help. Don't you need a Segmentation? Like

`ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);` ?

Comment: I tried doing that, it still has issue trying to read the letters or doesn't read any at all. The text output I got was just: "i."

Comment: Did you had look how the image looks like after the opencv thresholding in Line 4? Maybe the thresholding values makes trouble..

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to just read the letters without the thresholding..still the same results. I've had more success with letter recognition on captchas..so not sure what the issue is for something that appears to be rather simple.

Answer (score -1):

1. Read tesseract docs.
2. Tesseract is not designed to solve captchas (and captchas are designed to fool OCR)
3. LSTM was trained on words => your input is not word.

Comment: This is not a captcha, it's just text that has been slightly turned clockwise or counter-clockwise. I only mentioned captcha cause my previous work with tesseract was with simple captcha's and it worked fine..and the lettering for that was much harder to decipher. Although, I used my own generated traineddata for that, but despite anything I can't get it to recognize a single letter here.